# Crawl website from list of values using scrapy

Tags: python, scrapy, scrapy-pipeline

I have a list of NPIs which I want to scrape the names of the providers for from npidb.org 
The NPI values are stored in a csv file.

I am able to do it manually by pasting the URLs in the code. However, I am unable to figure out how to do it if I have a list of NPIs for each of which I want the provider names.

Here is my current code:

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.spider import BaseSpider



class MySpider(BaseSpider):
    name = "npidb"

    def start_requests(self):
        urls = [

            'https://npidb.org/npi-lookup/?npi=1366425381',
            'https://npidb.org/npi-lookup/?npi=1902873227',
        ]
        for url in urls:
            yield scrapy.Request(url=url, callback=self.parse)

    def parse(self, response):
        page = response.url.split("/")[-1]
        filename = 'npidb-%s.html' % page
        with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
            f.write(response.body)
        self.log('Saved file %s' % filename)
```

Comment: you want to provide all the `npi` values from a command line? text file?

Comment: The NPIs are stored in a csv file that was derived from another code.

Comment: What's the structure of the csv file? If you had each URL as an entry per line, you could write something like: open(file_name).read().split() and get a list of all the lines.

Comment: They are only the NPIs in there. The challenge is to paste them in the URL and get a Name associated with each NPI. This is a really easy thing probably, but I am a complete newbie and unable to crack it.

Answer (score 0):

Assume you have a list of npi from csv file, then you can simply use `format` to change the website address as following(I also add the part to get list from csv file. If you have it already, you can omit that part):

```
    def start_requests(self):
        # get npis from csv file
        npis = []
        with open('test.csv', 'r') as f:
            for line in f.readlines():
                l = line.strip()
                npis.append((l))
       # generate the list of address depending on npi
        start_urls = []
        for npi in npis:
            start_urls.append('https://npidb.org/npi-lookup/?npi={}'.format(npi))
        for url in start_urls:
            yield scrapy.Request(url=url, callback=self.parse)
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, it depends on the structure of your csv file, but if it contains the npis in separate lines, you could do something like

```
def start_requests(self):
    with open('npis.csv') as f:
        for line in f:
            yield scrapy.Request(
                url='https://npidb.org/npi-lookup/?npi={}'.format(line.strip()), 
                callback=self.parse
            )
```